# Difference between homogeneous and heterogeneous mixture

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions, mixtures

When i mix two equal but large number of stones it is possible (though extremely unlikely) that stone a and stone b perfectly segregate themselves into two halves or that they are uniformly distributed but we still call it a heterogeneous mixture because almost always this doesn't happen this is discontinuity in the pattern always given a large enough sample size is taken. However ink mixed in water is homogeneous yes it is distributed uniformly but the ink particles may seperate themselves and lose order and shift to one side of the container (very low chance but still a possibility at a very small time) So my question is how can we truly say if a mixture is homogeneous or heterogeneous when probability and approximations must be taken into account.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's incoherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homogenity/heterogenity is a conditional parameter.

Homogenity means that at given scale, resolution or sensitivity, you cannot tell the difference in properties in different places within the mixture.

Sand dunes are homogenous mixture, seen from far enough. Any matter is heterogenous, if observed at atomic level, because of its non-continuous, atom based nature.